# C# CLR This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, reporting-services, clr

Say I have this clr procedure
exec [SqlStoredProcedure1] 'param1=1,param2=2,param3=3'

And have it already coded to separate into different parameters

```
string[] initparam = reportParameters.Split(','); //PARAM STRING
string[] param = null; //PARAM SELECTOR
string[] paramvalues = new string[initparam.Length * 2];
int cursor=0;
for(int i=0; i < initparam.Length; i++)
    {
    param = initparam[i].Split('=');
    for (int j = 0; j < param.Length; j++)
        {
        paramvalues[cursor] = param[j];
        cursor++;
    }
}
int counter = 0;
foreach (ConsoleApp2.ReportService2005.ReportParameter rp in 
_parameters)
{      
    for(int i = 0; i < paramvalues.Length; i = i + 2)
    {
        if (string.Equals(paramvalues[i], rp.Name, 
        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
        parameters[_parameters.Length - totalParams] = new 
        ConsoleApp2.ReportExecution2005.ParameterValue();
        parameters[_parameters.Length - totalParams].Name = 
        rp.Name;
        parameters[_parameters.Length - totalParams].Value = 
        paramvalues[i + 1];
        }
}
SqlContext.Pipe.Send("names: " + parameters[counter].Name);
SqlContext.Pipe.Send("values: " + parameters[counter].Value);
counter++;
totalParams--;
}
re2005.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");
```

Pipe then outputs

```
Param1
1
Param2
2
Param3
3
```

However after hitting .SetExecutionParameters I would get an error in SSMS.

> This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report
>   parameter 'Param3'. To run or subscribe to this report, you must
>   provide a parameter value.
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportParameterValueNotSetException:
>   This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report
>   parameter 'Param3'. To run or subscribe to this report, you must
>   provide a parameter value.

I'm not seeing anything wrong in the code. The code works fine if thrown with a report with just one parameter, I'm not sure why it doesn't when hit with multiple parameters.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry. Had an issue where stack doesn't allow me to post unindented code. Not sure why it considered the Param1 1.... as code though.
Also sorry about the identation, i thought it was the issue.